# Default values not adding to mongoose Model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So this is an example of my schema I have for a user.

```js
    id: String,
    email: String,
    slug: {
        type: Object,
        phrase: {type: String, default: null},
    },
```

When I want to define a new user and save that user, I would do the following;

```js
const newUser = new User({
   id: 123,
   username: "CoolUser",
   email: "BillGates@google.com"
});
                
newUser.save();
```

But this does not save the "slug" object, It was my understanding, that since I a default value for it, it would auto populate with that default value. What can I do to make it auto generate without having to define the whole schema again when saving a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add default for `slug` property, and not for his sub-property. Try changing your schema like this:

```js
slug: {
  type: {
    phrase: { type: String },
  },
  default: {
    phrase: null 
  },
},
```

Comment: I then have the issue of trying to set phrase to a string as default.
Like if I want to set `phrase: ""` that works, but `phrase: "Test"` doesnt

Comment: Can you upload you code? `default: { phrase: "Test" }` should work.

Comment: Here is the hastebin code: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/pejuhiqabo.less

Comment: Can you upload it in the question with formatting?

Comment: Yeah here is the hastebin. https://toptal.com/developers/hastebin/pejuhiqabo.less

Comment: This is not the same example as the one in question. Can you create new question with new data? And please upload whole schema.

Comment: I added it as an anwser below

Comment: Can you post it as a new question. If I update the current answer for new example, then it will not be helpful for future visitors of this question.

Comment: No it's the same issue. Why would I make a new question?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const subschema = new Schema({
  phrase: {type: String, default: null},
}, { _id: false });
```

and in your original schema:

```
  id: String,
  email: String,
  slug: {
    type: subschema,
    default: () => ({})
  },
```

this should do the trick.

Comment: This doesn't help that much and is confusing because you didn't explain.